# the carry in most significant bit(on 3 digits)

Tags: binary, overflow, twos-complement, data-representation

Consider the two's complement representation on 3 bits:

3+2 causes overflow.

011+010=100 // why is it 100? I think it should be 101.

And what are the carry in to the most significant bit and carry out from the most significant bit in this case?

the textbook says the carry in to the most significant bit is 1, the carry out from the most significant bit is 0.

I think the text book is wrong. the carry in should be 0 and the carry out should be 1. Am I correct or the textbook is correct?

Please help. Thanks.

[Textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUXTL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Right *and* wrong, I would say, just like so much of life :-)

You're correct in stating that `011 + 010 = 101`. The link you posted gave the `100` value of `-4` which is a correct *interpretation* of that value, though not the correct value.

You can generally get the overflowed value by adding the two values *without* taking overflow into account, then subtracting the range (eight for a three-bit value) if it's more than half the range less one.

In other words, `3 + 2 = 5` but, since this is greater than three (half range less one), you subtract the range `8` to get `-3`, which is what your *correct* bit pattern is, `101`:

```
Bit pattern   Unsigned   Signed
-----------   --------   ------
   000           0          0
   001           1          1
   010           2          2
   011           3          3
   100           4         -4
   101           5         -3
   110           6         -2
   111           7         -1
```

---

However, adding the middle bits (with no carry over from the right bits) *does* actually give you a result of zero and carry of one.

That means the carry into the MSB (left bit) is *indeed* one. And, when adding those left digits (both zero) with that carry of one, you get one with a carry out of zero.

It may be that you're reading the textbook differently to me but we may have to give it the benefit of the doubt here.

Comment: Thank you, I kind of have figured out what it is about now.